# During running android test with Espresso application start on the home page with logged in state

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, android-espresso

I create automation tests for android application using Espresso framework.
But for any test I run - application stars on the Home page (second page after user login) for some reason. I reinstall my emulator to make sure it doesn't cash anything - but after first test run (before the first test step) - application runs on the Home screen. Does anybody has something like this?

Comment: How does your test setup look like, if you can share the piece of code there. Which activity gets launched or how are the ActivityTestRules ?

Comment: @ponkape I doesn't have any setup in before and my rule is: " ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);"
I'm really new in espresso and probably do something wrong

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet, which says to the Espresso, which activity should use when starting the test. (Please check the JUnit version also).

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class clickButtonTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<YourActivityName> mActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(YourActivityName.class);
    private YourActivityName mainActivity;


    @Before
    public void setActivity() {
        mainActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
        // Here you add required initializations / definitions
    }

    @Test
    public void clickButton () {

        // Click on button
        onView(withId(R.id.button_id)).perform(click());
```

ActivityTestRule you give the Activity you want to Espresso to perform, so that view will be opened when you start the test. In this case, you need to find the right activity, which should be in this case User Login screen? To find the activities in your applications, you need to open AndroidManifest.xml and find a suitable activity. [About AndroidManifest.xml](https://www.javatpoint.com/AndroidManifest-xml-file-in-android)

After you find the right activity, fill that to "YouActivityName" blocks. Then fill up the @Test as it should be. It depends on how you plan to design the test cases, but good practices are that tests are independent with each other that they are not relying on each other because that usually causes flakiness.

Also, good resources to read about Gradle, animations and others with Espresso. [Espresso Setup](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup)